# Does a Generalization of the equivalence of Weak Convergence and Convergence of the CDF to arbitrary Generators exist?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

As is known, the convergence of cumulative distribution functions (CDF) in all continuous points of the "target" CDF implies weak convergence. Now pointwise convergence of CDF in all continuous points is basically by definition, that:

$$\mu_n((-\infty,x])\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu((-\infty,x])\quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}:\mu(\{x\})=0$$

Which looks extremely similar to:
$$(*) \quad\mu_n(A)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A) \quad \forall A \in B(\mathbb{R}):\mu(\partial A)=0$$

Which is either the definition or equivalent to the definition (Portmanteau-Thm) of weak convergence. The difference is that for convergence of CDF, $(*)$ is only required on the Generator $\mathcal{E}=\{(-\infty,x]:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ of the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra.

Now two measures are equal if you can show that they are equal on a $\cap$-stable Generator. A special case of this is the Generator $\{(a,b]:a\in\mathbb{R}\cup\{-\infty\}, b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ which you get with:
$$\mu((a,b])=\mu((-\infty,b])-\mu((-\infty,a])=F(b)-F(a)$$
out of the CDF. So the natural Question to ask is: Can you do something similar for Weak Convergence? If it works for one Generator - maybe it works for all, or at least a special subset of Generators?

$\cap$-stability is certainly neccessary for this to work, as it is already required to show that two meassures are equal. So you could just recycle any Counterexamples that exist for that. If we have $\cap$-stability, one way to show this would be with the Monotone class theorem. This would require to show that 
$$ \{A \in B(\mathbb{R}) : (\mu_n(A)\rightarrow \mu(A))\lor(\mu(\partial A)\neq 0)\}$$
is a Dynkin System. The issue here is, that the "or" gets in the way, when you try to show simple things as unions. As it is hard to find a formula for the new Boundary in the first place and additionaly you could have the case where A and B have Borders with weight but the union has this part of the border inside of the set and a Null set as a border. Now you would have to show that $\mu_n(A\cup B)\rightarrow\mu(A\cup B)$  without beeing able to use convergence of A or B.

Now if A and B are "far away" from each other you get that the Boundry of $A\cup B$ is $(\partial A) \cup (\partial B)$ If they touch in our example that works (Intervalls) you get a new Intervall which is in the Generator. So maybe asking that touching unions are in the Generator again is necessary. But that would make this mostly boring.

Comment: while the tumbleweed badge is nice I guess - I would prefer ideas/answers ;-)